# ac-php package not working in emacs

Tags: emacs, package

I'm trying to installe 
    `ac-php` `emacs` package.  I installed it successfully from melpa but can't figure how to use.
Here's the screenshots of what happened. 
Package installed 
[image: installed]

 Configuration as described in [ac-php](https://github.com/xcwen/ac-php)
[image: Configuration]

No option for 
    `ac-php-*`!
[image]

 
How to solve it? Please help

Comment: Shows your code (js and html)

Comment: Youre fiddle link is incorrect.

Comment: You need to improve your post, posting more specifically your problem, and attaching your code..

Comment: You're asking about a PHP-related package, but MattLaza's answer (which apparently does solve the issue) is about javascript, not PHP. I can't tell whether you've even loaded a PHP file. The question remains rather unclear.

Comment: I've edited the previous question because I got ban for posting :(
Please up vote to help me to create new question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You issue here is your $('.to-translate').click() is being triggered every time you click on the input, which is then recreating the input every time.

I have updated your fiddle with a fix

https://jsfiddle.net/pcf331u5/

```
tpl += '<div id="'+iid+'" class="bg-warning"><p class="to-translate">'+text+'</p></div>';

$('.to-translate').click(function(){
$(this).parent().html('<input type="text" name="" class="form-control    ttxti">'); 
});
```

I have added a p element inside of your div which contains the to-translate class. When the click event is triggered the parent (div) replaces the content with the input

Comment: No worries. Can you please mark this answer as correct :)